# Trigger Manual Retile Freetile JS Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm using the excellent [freetile.js plugin](http://yconst.com/web/freetile/) from Yannis Chatzikonstantinou. I need to manually trigger a re-tile of the elements. I can't see how to do this from the documentation.

The re-tile happens perfectly on `window.resize`. The function `windowResizeCallback()` is called which handles it, but I don't know how to trigger/fire this function manually (JS is not my strong suit).

The freetile source is available here: https://github.com/yconst/Freetile/blob/master/jquery.freetile.js

How can I manually trigger the re-tile function? Thanks.

-- edit --

The reason I need this is because elements are not arranged correctly when the page first loads. They are positioned using % in the CSS (this is required). I've created a Fiddle with the code, but that of course works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/ABQ8m/1/

Also, I've tried to initialise the plugin twice, but that causes all kinds of problems, especially with images:

```
jQuery('.masonry-container').freetile().freetile({ ... options ... });
```